# Sorting an array of objects by an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like so;

```
var orders = [
  {
    status: "pending"
  },
  {
    status: "received"
  },
  {
    status: "sent"
  },
  {
    status: "pending"
  }
]
```

I want to sort this array of objects based on the value of the `status` key, but so that the order of the objects matches the order of the array of the possible values of the `status` key;

```
var statuses = ["pending", "sent", "received"]
```

Therefore, after sorting, the two `"pending"` objects would be first, followed by the `"sent"` object, and finally the `"received"` object.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be better if `statuses` were an object, with the status names being property names and the values of the properties being the sort weights. Then your sort comparison function could just difference the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sort()` and `indexOf()`.

```js
var orders = [{
  status: "pending"
}, {
  status: "received"
}, {
  status: "sent"
}, {
  status: "pending"
}]
var statuses = ["pending", "sent", "received"]

var result = orders.sort(function(a, b) {
  return statuses.indexOf(a.status) - statuses.indexOf(b.status)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort()` function:

```js
var statuses = ["pending", "sent", "received"];
var orders = [
  {
    status: "pending"
  },
  {
    status: "received"
  },
  {
    status: "sent"
  },
  {
    status: "pending"
  }
];

orders.sort(function(a, b) {
  return statuses.indexOf(a.status) - statuses.indexOf(b.status); 
});

console.log(orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort the array of objects. Where use an object to store the index of keys which helps to avoid using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method(which is slower).

```js
var orders = [{
  status: "pending"
}, {
  status: "received"
}, {
  status: "sent"
}, {
  status: "pending"
}];

var statuses = ["pending", "sent", "received"];

// generate the object which holds the index in array
// or use an object instead of array which holds the index
var index = statuses.reduce(function(obj, k, i) {
  obj[k] = i;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(
  orders.sort(function(a, b) {
    return index[a.status] - index[b.status];
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object as hash table for the sort order.

```js
var orders = [{ status: "pending" }, { status: "received" }, { status: "sent" }, { status: "pending" }],
    statuses = { pending: 1, sent: 2, received: 3 };

orders.sort(function (a, b) {
    return statuses[a.status] - statuses[b.status];
});

console.log(orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use methods like `indexOf()` within sort callback but more efficient is to build hashmap of the indices first

```
var statIndex = statuses.reduce(function(a,c,i){
   a[c] = i;
   return a
},{})

orders.sort(function(a,b){
   return statIndex[a.status] - statIndex[b.status]
})
```